# Play Framework - debug & release configurations?

Tags: scala, playframework, configuration

When developing a Play application, we use the standard [configuration file](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Configuration) in `conf/application.conf`. How can I use different conf files depending on whether I'm in debug or release mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have `prod.conf` and `debug.conf` both in the `conf` folder, you can add the following system property:

```
-Dconfig.resource=(prod|debug).conf
```

if the files can't be packaged in the app in the `conf` folder and have to be external, for example, in `/opt/conf`, then you can add the following instead:

```
-Dconfig.file=/opt/conf/(prod|debug).conf
```

They can inherit a common configuration file and override values:

```
include "application.conf"
key.to.override=blah
```

See [reference](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ProductionConfiguration#Specifying-an-alternate-configuration-file) for more on this.

Comment: Thanks! I obviously haven't learned yet to find answers in the Play documentation. I wonder if it's only my issue...